# KUbuntu install doesn't use boot manager

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows-10

I have a GPT based disk (with currently only 2 OS partitions)
The current partitioning scheme looks like this

| partition | type | mount point | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/sda1 | FAT32 | /boot/efi (locked) | 100M |
| /dev/sda2 | unknown | Microsoft reserved | 16M |
| /dev/sda3 | ntfs | (Not mounted) | 200G |
| /dev/sda4 | ntfs | (Not mounted) | 500M |
| /dev/sda5 | ext4 | / | 200G |
| /dev/sda6 | ext4 | /home | 50G |
| unallocated |  |  | rest (nearly 500G) that is going to partitioned later |

I went through the whole KUbuntu setup using image downloaded (USB boot if that matters). Sequence was Windows 10 install first, followed by KUbuntu install.

**Expected:**
KUbuntu to recognize an existing OS install and pick up a boot manager and install it with selection for KUbuntu and windows 10.

**Actual:**
KUbuntu boots up directly.

Q: What am I missing?